# Django saving Form with Image File Issue

Tags: python, html, django, file, save

I am trying to Upload an Image file from a simple HMTL form I got the following error:

**'MultiValueDict' object has no attribute '_committed'**

I am not using forms cause in this same way I will need to upload many files at once and for what I know Djangoforms only allow to upload one file at once.

So using the normal way seems not working...

The code structure is as follows:

**Models.py**

```
class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    account_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/%Y/%m/%d')
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ProfileImage'
```

**Html**

```
  <form  id="fileinfo" name="fileinfo" action="profileimage" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
      {% csrf_token %}
      <table>
          <tr>
             <input type="file" size="60" id="myfile" name="myfile" multiple="false" value="Profile Picture"
             accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
             <div id="accresult" name="accresult"></div>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
```

**Views.py**

```
def profile_image(request):
    profile_image = ProfileImage(account_id=request.session.get('memberid', False), image=request.FILES,  profile='', description='')
    try:          
      print 'Userid: ', profile_image.account_id
      print 'File sent...', profile_image.image
      profile_image.save()
    except Exception as err:
       print 'Error: ', err.message
    useraccount = request.session.get('useraccount', False)
    return render(request, 'profileImage.html', {'useraccount': useraccount, 'image': profile_image})
```

The parameter arrives correctly however when trying to `save()` the error comes I have just tried in many ways so will really appreciate your help.

Comment: what's the error? what does print 'Error: ', err.message  show?

Answer (score 0):

The `request.FILES` is a list of file. You need to specify which file you want to pass to the `image` parameter. Like this one.

```
profile_image = ProfileImage(account_id=request.session.get('memberid', False), image=request.FILES[0],  profile='', description='')
```

This is not very good because it will raise an exception if there is no files. You might need to use [Django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/) for better form handling.